# #ifdef works, #ifndef gives error?

Tags: gcc, g++, cygwin

### Using gcc and g++ version 4.5.3 with cygwin,  I made this program and found that #ifndef doesn't seem to work right.

```
#ifndef BLAH
#define <stdio.h>
#endif
int main(){
 return 0;
}
```

---

Using #ifdef seems to work fine though.
The error I'm getting is "macro names must be identifiers".

Does #ifndef require something specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define <stdio.h>
/*  ^
     \
      --- this should be #include
*/
```

[Example](http://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/b66e5ad/deps/hiredis/example-ae.c#L1)

Comment: rofl,  I can't believe I missed that!  wow I feel stupid. I was comparing it to code that I wrote that used it correctly too... Thank you.